# How to merge pandas dataset onto itself based on a condition and a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

To best illustrate consider the following SQL Illustration:
Table StockPrices, BarSeqId is a sequential number where each increment is information from next minute of trading.

The goal to achieve in pandas data frame is to transform this data:

```
StockPrice    BarSeqId LongProfitTarget
105           0           109
100           1           105
103           2           107
103           3           108
104           4           110
105           5           113
```

into this data:

```
StockPrice    BarSeqId    LongProfitTarget  TargetHitBarSeqId
106           0           109               Nan
100           1           105               3 
103           2           107               5
105           3           108               Nan
104           4           110               Nan
107           5           113               Nan
```

to create a new column which describes at which soonest sequential time-frame a price target will be hit in the future from the current time-frame

Here is how it could be achieved in SQL:

```
SELECT S1.StockPrice, S1.BarSeqId, S1.LongProfitTarget, 
   min(S2.BarSeqId) as TargetHitBarSeqId
FROM StockPrices S1
   left outer join StockPrices S2 on S1.BarSeqId<s2.BarSeqId and 
  S2.StockPrice>=S1.LongProfitTarget
GROUP BY S1.StockPrice, S1.BarSeqId, S1.LongProfitTarget
```

I would like the answer to be as follows:

```
 someDataFrame['TargetHitBarSeqId'] = (pandas expression here ...**
```

assume that someDataFrame already has columns: StockPrice, BarSeqId, LongProfitTarget

data edited to illustrate case
so in the second row result should be

```
100           1           105               3
```

and NOT

```
100           1           105               0
```

since 3 and not 0 occurs after 1.

It is important that the barseq in question shall occur in the future (greater than current BarSeq)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'StockPrice':[105,100,103,105,104,107],'BarSeqId':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
          'LongProfitTarget':[109,105,107,108,110,113]})
def get_barseqid(longProfitTarget):
    try:
        idx = df.StockPrice[df.StockPrice >= longProfitTarget].index[0]
        return df.iloc[idx].BarSeqId
    except:
        return np.nan

df['TargetHitBarSeqId'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_barseqid(row['LongProfitTarget']), axis=1)
```

Comment: To format better, you should place 4 spaces before each row of a table in a question. I did the first table as an example.

Comment: Thanks - this is my 1st ask ever on stack. Does this explain the question well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = <your input data frame>

def get_barseqid(longProfitTarget):
    try:
        idx = df.StockPrice[df.StockPrice >= longProfitTarget].index[0]
        return df.iloc[idx].BarSeqId
    except:
        return np.nan

df['TargetHitBarSeqId'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_barseqid(row['LongProfitTarget']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   StockPrice  BarSeqId  LongProfitTarget  TargetHitBarSeqId
0         100         1               105                3.0
1         103         2               107                5.0
2         105         3               108                NaN
3         104         4               110                NaN
4         107         5               113                NaN
```

Comment: See clarification BarSeq must be in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from itertools import islice
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'StockPrice':[105,100,103,105,104,107],'BarSeqId':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
              'LongProfitTarget':[109,105,107,108,110,113]})
def get_barseqid(longProfitTarget,barseq):
    try:
        idx = df[(df.StockPrice >= longProfitTarget) & (df.BarSeqId>barseq)].index[0]
        return df.iloc[idx].BarSeqId
    except:
        return np.nan

df['TargetHitBarSeqId'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_barseqid(row['LongProfitTarget'], row['BarSeqId']), axis=1)
df
```

The key misunderstanding for me was a need to use & operator instead of regular 'or'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is manageable, consider a cross join followed by filter and `groupby`, which would replicate the SQL query:

```
cdf = pd.merge(df.assign(key=1), df.assign(key=1), on='key', suffixes=['','_'])\
            .query('(BarSeqId < BarSeqId_) & (LongProfitTarget <= StockPrice_)')\
            .groupby(['StockPrice', 'BarSeqId', 'LongProfitTarget'])['BarSeqId_'].min()

print(cdf)
# StockPrice  BarSeqId  LongProfitTarget
# 100         1         105                 3
# 103         2         107                 5
# Name: BarSeqId_, dtype: int64
```